# Keep cell references fixed after inserting line in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if there is a way to make a cell reference even more static than the $ command in excel. Specifically, I have a summary line at the top of my sheet that simply references a cell on the top line of my data (in this case, cell C1 is "=I$5"), which is below. When I have new data, I update the sheet by inserting a new row at the top, then fill in the data. As soon as I do this, C1 automatically changes to "=I$6". Is there a way to stop this from happening without using VBA?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always liked to use `=INDIRECT("$I$5")` for this as it makes the formulas more readable. Some speed impact though.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, it doesn't matter whether or not you use the dollar signs that indicate an absolute range; since Excel will never modify the value between the double quotation marks, it will always be absolute. If you want to make a permanent relative reference, (e.g. always five cells left no matter how the spreadsheet is altered) you'd need to use `OFFSET()` with the address of the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

C1: =INDEX($1:$1048576,12,5)